# Problem using factors as independent variables in best subsets regression (leaps or regsubsets)

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

I am trying to do best subsets regression in R.  Using either `leaps()` or `regsubsets()` (from the `leaps` package), it works perfectly well if all my independent (explanatory) variables are numeric.  But if I include a factor, it fails with the error message:

> Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = NCOL(x) + int,  : 
>     NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = NCOL(x) + int,  :
>     only the first string in a char vector used in .Fortran

I have crawled all over my dataset, and it absolutely does not have any `NA`/`NaN`/`Inf` values in it; I have also tried generating artificial factor values rather than using the ones out of my data set, and I get the same result.  If I create dummy variables outside R to represent the factor values, then it runs perfectly well, so it cannot be anything to do with the data itself.  I have tried it with and without labels for the factor levels, and with numerical or character factor values in the original data: same result in every case.  Here's one of the ways I used:

```
zoo1 <- within(panda, AltitudeZoo1 <- relevel(factor(Altitude), "2134"))
```

Yet documentation online claims that factors can be used in `leaps()`, e.g. [this document](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html).  I have found various reports, including within StackOverflow, of roughly the same error message (usually differing in the "arg" number complained of), but all concern the `randomForest` routine.

It makes no difference whether I use `leaps()` or `regsubsets()`.

Any ideas?  The workaround is to go back to creating dummy variables outside R, but that is annoying.

Here is a reproducible example: first the code

```
reprex = read.csv("reprexdata.csv", head = T)
library(leaps)

##creating dummy variable
reprex$xfactordata.f<-factor(reprex$xfactordata)
##checking dummy variables work ok with simple regression
m<-lm(reprex$y~reprex$x1data+reprex$x2data+reprex$xfactordata.f) 
summary(m)

##now try best subsets regression
y<-reprex$y
x <- reprex[,c (2,3,5)] ## picks up x1data, x2data, xfactordata.f
Z <- leaps(x,y, method = "adjr2", nbest = 1) ## running leaps subset regression
Z
```

Next, the data I tested the above code on, which duly produced the error reported earlier (33 rows):

```
ydata   x1data  x2data  xfactordata
139.3983228 2   0.555555556 2134
159.4909669 1   0.28125 2134
162.979101  0   0   1780
158.523721  0   0   1780
167.9430665 1   0.526509081 2134
150.4105583 1   0.21875 2134
136.6799004 2   8.428819444 2134
142.9603016 1   0.026041667 2134
149.3782133 1   0.364583333 2134
162.3022502 0   2.725694444 2084
159.8686527 0   1.085069444 2084
129.5367811 0   14.04513889 2084
133.8219284 0   8.697916667 2084
152.7590267 2   2.81421023  2134
167.6079507 1   0.251736111 1780
157.4867615 2   0.915798611 2134
146.8897681 2   1.40625 2134
151.4678525 1   0.769842804 2134
174.3412577 2   2.612847222 2084
150.0527068 2   0.885416667 2134
139.3348421 1   2.560763889 2134
159.4110442 2   1.66626408  2134
164.2695334 2   0.958333333 2134
154.5591851 1   1.980372102 2134
160.5290024 1   1.225   2134
154.4028751 1   1.370983414 2134
144.0339001 1   0.520833333 2134
145.5653995 2   0   2134
161.8175311 1   1.271701389 2134
139.338698  1   3.8875  2134
163.2222006 1   0.703125    2084
146.2958403 1   0   2134
```

Comment: From what I can tell so far you just can't (I will check the document you linked more carefully).  `model.matrix()` is your friend.  I will write up an answer if/when I get a chance.  The only thing I would caution about is that independently selecting dummy variables that constitute part of a categorical variable for inclusion/exclusion seems potentially weird/uninterpretable.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? `leaps` takes only matrices, `regsubsets` takes a formula (and converts the data to a matrix)

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at this, Ben.  I will edit the post to include a reprex.  On your point about interpretation, yes, that could be weird, but in some contexts it makes sense.  Example (not the context we were using): examining behaviour on some test of individuals who either have no diagnosed disorder, or one of several (mutually exclusive) diagnoses.  Then no-diagnosis becomes the reference category for the diagnosis dummy variables, and the best-subsets procedure helps you identify which (if any) diagnoses are associated with unusual behaviour on your test

Comment: reprex now added

Answer (score 0):

The `leaps()` function requires a *model matrix* (i.e. a matrix of numeric values only, while `regsubsets` can take a formula argument (which automatically constructs a model matrix from a set of specified predictors, possibly including factors); the [example you link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html) (I think I'd call this an "example", not "documentation"; the reference documentation from the package (e.g. [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaps/versions/3.0/topics/leaps)) doesn't anywhere show an example or say explicitly that factors are allowed (it says only that `x` is "a matrix of predictors", which technically wouldn't allow factors - factors are converted to `character` when you try to put them into a matrix).

Here's how to convert a set of predictors including one or more factors into a numeric matrix of predictions (including the factors as multiple dummy variables):

```
x <- model.matrix(~x1data+x2data+xfactordata.f, data=reprex)
Z <- leaps(x, reprex$y, method="adjr2", nbest=1)
```

in your particular example this returns an error

> leaps requires full-rank design matrix; use regsubsets()

but I think this is because your example is artificially small (you happened to put together a set of perfectly collinear predictors).

As advertised, `regsubsets()` does this step for you automatically if you specify a formula:

```
regsubsets(y~x1data+x2data+xfactordata.f, data=reprex)
```

If you know you want to use all of the columns in a data frame a predictors except for the response variable, you can say  `regsubsets(y~., data=reprex)`, or in this case `regsubsets(y ~ . - xfactordata)` (since don't want both `xfactordata` and `xfactordata.f` in the model)